# Something's wrong with mouseOver() and multiples elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a some sort of small html game. 
Below is my code :

```
<div id="BS">
        <img style="position:absolute; top:375px; left:500px; width:176px; height:286px;" onmouseover="mouseOver()" src="Pictures/BS1.png"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function mouseOver() {
                document.getElementById("BS").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:375px; left:500px; width:176px; height:286px;" src="Pictures/BS2.png" onmouseout="mouseOut()"/>';
                }
            function mouseOut() {
                document.getElementById("BS").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:375px; left:500px; width:176px; height:286px;" src="Pictures/BS1.png" onmouseover="mouseOver()"/>';
            }
    </script>

  <div id="Radio">
        <img style="position:absolute; top:478px; left:768px; width:101px; height:71px;" onmouseover="mouseOver()" src="Pictures/radio1.png"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function mouseOver() {
                document.getElementById("Radio").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:478px; left:768px; width:101px; height:71px;" src="Pictures/radio2.png" onmouseout="mouseOut()"/>';
                }
            function mouseOut() {
                document.getElementById("Radio").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:478px; left:768px; width:101px; height:71px;" src="Pictures/radio1.png" onmouseover="mouseOver()"/>';
            }
    </script>
```

The issue is, only the last item coded ( here, the `Radio` ) is working when I'm putting my cursor onto it. So i was wondering, is there a way to fix this ? Cause I did plan to put at least 2 more elements ...
Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Each time you declare those functions you overwrite previous instances

Answer (score 0):

You Have both function names `mouseOver` and `mouseOut`, so the second time you are creating it, you are overwriting the first one. If you name them `mouseBsOver` and `mouseRadioOver`, then assign them that way, it will work.

```
<div id="BS">
    <img style="position:absolute; top:375px; left:500px; width:176px; height:286px;" onmouseover="mouseBsOver()" src="Pictures/BS1.png"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function mouseBsOver() {
            document.getElementById("BS").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:375px; left:500px; width:176px; height:286px;" src="Pictures/BS2.png" onmouseout="mouseOut()"/>';
            }
        function mouseBsOut() {
            document.getElementById("BS").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:375px; left:500px; width:176px; height:286px;" src="Pictures/BS1.png" onmouseover="mouseOver()"/>';
        }
</script>

<div id="Radio">
    <img style="position:absolute; top:478px; left:768px; width:101px; height:71px;" onmouseover="mouseRadioOver()" src="Pictures/radio1.png"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function mouseRadioOver() {
            document.getElementById("Radio").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:478px; left:768px; width:101px; height:71px;" src="Pictures/radio2.png" onmouseout="mouseOut()"/>';
            }
        function mouseRadioOut() {
            document.getElementById("Radio").innerHTML = '<img style="position:absolute; top:478px; left:768px; width:101px; height:71px;" src="Pictures/radio1.png" onmouseover="mouseOver()"/>';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: so I just have to replace mouseOver by mouseKeyOver and mouseOut by mouseKeyOut ?

Comment: I put the working code in the answer, have you tried it? You weren't using the mouseOut functions, so I also didn't include them, but I figured you would know how to get those working when you want.

Answer (score -1):

The way it works

```js
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "64px";
    x.style.width = "64px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "32px";
    x.style.width = "32px";
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley">
```

Or You can do it another way

```html
<h1 onmouseover="style.color='red'" onmouseout="style.color='black'">Mouse over this text</h1>
```